# What is the equivalent of `fs.readFileSync` but in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I read a wasm file in Node with `fs.readFileSync` I get the file in the format I want but when I try and do the exact same thing in the browser with the file reader I somehow get the wrong format?

What is the equivalent of `fs.readFileSync` but in the browser?

Does `fs.readFileSync` treat the file as an array buffer or a Binary string or something else?

```
<input type="file" onchange="_readWasmFile">
```

and the js

```
_readWasmFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  reader.onload = () => {
      this.sendWasm = reader.result;
  };
}
```

Comment: The browser doesn't have access to the filesystem.

Comment: there is no direct equivalent, thankfully

Comment: Through an input of type file it does

Comment: File access can be done, but only by direct interactive use of an `<input type="file">` or a drag-and-drop enabled element.

Comment: Alnitak I agree, this is exactly what I'm trying to do, I have expanded the example above to make this clear

Comment: @Bill I don't know if it's possible to access the contents via the change event like that.   I have previously performed local file I/O using drag and drop.

Comment: either way, you can't AFAIK perform synchronous file reads, only async ones.

Comment: seen this?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: FileReader examples [here in this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications).  Lots of already functioning code examples that you should be able to draw from.

Comment: There are lots of examples, my question is which is the equivalent

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for this @Bill?

Answer (score 0):

When using [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) in the browser, you basically have 3 options. The closest to Node's `readFileSync()` seems to be the `readAsText()` method;

```
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  
  //Option 1 
   reader.readAsText(file);
  //Option 2
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  //Option 3
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

With `readAsText()`, you can specify the encoding to ensure you are reading the file correctly:

```
reader.readAsText(file, 'utf-8');
```

Node's `readFileSync()` method also has an optional property to specify the encoding:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt',
{ encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' });
```